# qualifying confilicting functions in Julia

Tags: julia

I have following conflicting exports:

```
using DataFrames
using DataStructures
```

Following returns an error:

```
tail(dfc)
WARNING: both DataStructures and DataFrames export "tail"; uses of it in module Main must be qualified
ERROR: UndefVarError: tail not defined
```

I saw this syntax on one forum, but it still fails:

```
DataFrames::tail(dfc)
ERROR: UndefVarError: tail not defined
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This appears to work for julia version 0.4.6:

```
julia> using DataFrames, DataStructures

julia> lst = list(1, 2, 3)
list(1, 2, 3)

julia> DataStructures.tail(lst)
list(2, 3)
```

The `::` is used for specifying type information.